# How to disable DTD validation in XSL function 'document()' (xalan-j)

Tags: java, xslt, dtd, xalan

XSL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:htm="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="source" select="document('test.html')"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

test.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
Bla-Bla-bla
</body>
</html>
```

When test.html contains DOCTYPE declaration, XSL transformation takes about 2 minutes.
When I remove DOCTYPE declaration in test.html, XSL transformation takes about 100 ms.
Is there a way in xalan-j to disable DTD validation for internal loading of XML via XSL document() function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but you may want to rethink trying to disable the DTD handling, because the HTML may contain entities (such as `&nbsp;`) that are defined in the DTD and are not standard XML.  A better question might be simply how to stop DTD handling from taking so long. :)

Comment: Agree with you, JLRishe. The main question is how to improve performance.

Comment: why doctype comes after xml declaration?

Comment: i thik [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) link will be useful.

Comment: Thank you, Sugar. But even if I remove xml declaration (according to correct HTML doctype declaration), the performance is still very bad - about 2 min.

Comment: Take a look at XML catalogs. Here is a good article: http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html.

Comment: @Sugar - The doctype declaration must come after the xml declaration. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd (XML 1.0) and http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-prolog-dtd (XML 1.1)

Comment: Did you tried to download DTD and use it localy

Comment: I tried to use local catalog but without success

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable validation.  You need to install either a local caching proxy or a catalog and a local copy of the DTDs you use most often.

The process is taking a long time because [W3C serves DTD files very slowly](http://www.w3.org/Help/Webmaster.html#slowdtd) as a way of discouraging excessive DTD traffic.

Use a local catalog, or use a local caching proxy.